# Pgfplots node positioning acting strangely

Tags: pgfplots

To put it simply, why is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    ticks=none,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={anchor=west}
    ]
    \addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates { (3,2) };
    \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs: 3,0 ) {$x_\circ$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

producing this:

[image]

What I would like to see is the $x_\circ$ right underneath the the blue stem. What is going on here and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: just remove `axis cs:`

Comment: @sergiokapone That's what I thought too but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @TheSodesa In my case, I just change on `\node[anchor=south] at (3,0) {$x_\circ$};` and it is work fine. May be you need to update `pgfplots`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the axis range. Just add the option `ymin=0` and it will behave as you expect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    clip=false,
    ticks=none,
    axis y line=none,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    xlabel style={anchor=west},
    ymin=0
    ]
    \addplot+[ycomb] plot coordinates { (3,2) };
    \node[anchor=north] at (axis cs: 3,0) {$x_\circ$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```